# Ckeditor Image tab breaks responsive layout

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When including a URL for "filebrowserUploadUrl" this adds the "Link" and "Upload" tabs to the the image properties window.

The problem is these two new tabs make the window a fixed pixel size that is potentially wider that the screen size. For mobile it is indeed wider so the image tab cannot be properly used on mobile.

In fact the link window is also affected.

Is there any setting or plugin that can be used to aid this situation. If not what would be the most sensible approach for solving the problem? CSS media queries or editing the Javascript source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These CSS rules seem to have fixed it, this is for the moono-lisa skin.

```
a.cke_dialog_tab{
    min-width: auto !important;
}

.cke_dialog .ImagePreviewBox{
    width: auto !important;
}
```